# Problem with jitters with Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, surface, creality

Recently I realized that I have been getting jitter-like rough surfaces on round parts of my models from my Ender 3. The jitters happen on the sides of the model, so the jitters would be happening in the X and Y. The weird thing is that some parts are smooth and others have jitters. Has anyone else encountered this problem? How do I solve it?

Here is a photo of my hovercraft where it happened the most. (This is all one piece)  As you can see, the section next to the jitters is completely clean. I'm not really sure about what is going on here.

[image: Example of jitters on print surface]

Comment: I can't answer it directly but let's do some debugging. Are you sure your gcode and STL files are good (default speeds etc...)? Can you check the tightness of timing belts in the axes? Did you try with different infill settings, are the results are same?

Comment: I just tightened the timing belts, but I still get the same result. The bumps still happen regardless of the infill. I'm not really sure if it is my slicer, or if it may be something with the steppers.